# play/pause two audio sources at once HTML5 audio?

Tags: html, html5-audio

I want to play/pause two audio files by using single control anyone can please help.

if I click on play button the two audio files should stop and same pause also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do this in js for each of your audio tag :

```
var a = document.getElementById("audio1");
a.play();
```

for example :

```
var audioElements = ['audio1','audio2'];
function playAudio() {
  for(i = 0; i < audioElements.length;i++) {
    document.getElementById(audioElements[i]).play();
  }
}


function pauseAudio() {
  for(i = 0; i < audioElements.length;i++) {
    document.getElementById(audioElements[i]).pause();
  }
}
```